# The same regex pattern that works fine doesn't work implemented into a Class

Tags: python, regex, oop

Why this code retrieves one result:

```
import re

input_file = open("nota_simple.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
text_to_search = input_file.read()

pattern = re.compile("(?<=FINCA Nº: ).*")

result = pattern.search(text_to_search)
print(result.group())
```

But this other doesn't match anything?  (None is the result)

```
import re

class PropertyNumber(object):
    regex_pattern = re.compile("(?<=FINCA Nº: ).*")

    def __init__(self, str):
        self.text_to_search = str
        self.text_found = ""

    def search_p_number(self):
        matched_p_number = PropertyNumber.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_p_number)
        self.text_found = matched_p_number.group()

def main():
    file_input = open("nota_simple.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    property_report = file_input.read()
    property_number = PropertyNumber(property_report)
    print(property_number.search_p_number())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That I did it is just to implement a Class to handle the data I need to retrieve from the text.

So the regex pattern isn't the issue, I believe that is in the OOP implementation (I'm noob in OOP).

Comment: your search_p_number has no return value.

Comment: OMG! You're all right!  First I thought to use the attribute value then I changed my opinion and decided to use the method as a 'getter', since I've read that it's a better practise. Do you think any variables or attributes spares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Suggested tweaks.

import re

class PropertyNumber(object):

    def __init__(self, str, pattern = "(?<=FINCA Nº: ).*"):
        self.regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self.text_to_search = str
        self.text_found = ""

    def search_p_number(self):
        matched_p_number = self.regex_pattern.search(self.text_to_search)
        print(self.text_to_search)
        print(matched_p_number)
        self.text_found = matched_p_number.group()
        return self.text_found

def main():
    file_input = open("nota_simple.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
    property_report = file_input.read()
    property_number = PropertyNumber(property_report)
    print(property_number.search_p_number())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

add `return self.text_found`  to `search_p_number()` method